# custom comparison for built-in containers

Tags: python, comparison

In my code there's numerous comparisons for equality of various containers (list, dict, etc.). The keys and values of the containers are of types float, bool, int, and str. The built-in == and != worked perfectly fine.

I just learned that the floats used in the values of the containers must be compared using a custom comparison function. I've written that function already (let's call it approxEqual(), and assume that it takes two floats and return True if they are judged to be equal and False otherwise).

I prefer that the changes to the existing code are kept to a minimum. (New classes/functions/etc can be as complicated as necessary.)

Example:

```
if dict1 != dict2:
  raise DataMismatch
```

The `dict1 != dict2` condition needs to be rewritten so that any floats used in values of dict1 and dict2 are compared using approxEqual function instead of `__eq__`.

The actual contents of dictionaries comes from various sources (parsing files, calculations, etc.).

Note: I [asked a question earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3854047/336527) about how to override built-in float's **eq**. That would have been an easy solution, but I learned that Python doesn't allow overriding built-in types' `__eq__` operator. Hence this new question.

Comment: What is your question? If you have the function already, what's the problem?

Comment: Could you provide some example code that you expect to work differently?

Comment: Already answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854047/approximate-comparison-in-python

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only route to altering the way built-in containers check equality is to make them contain as values, instead of the "originals", *wrapped* values (wrapped in a class that overrides `__eq__` and `__ne__`).  This is if you need to alter the way the containers themselves use equality checking, e.g. for the purpose of the `in` operator where the right-hand side operand is a list -- as well as in containers' method such as their own `__eq__` (`type(x).__eq__(y)` is the typical way Python will perform internally what you code as `x == y`).

If what you're talking about is performing **your own** equality checks (*without* altering the checks performed internally by the containers themselves), then the only way is to change every `cont1 == cont2` into (e.g.) `same(cont1, cont2, value_same)` where `value_same` is a function accepting two values and returning `True` or `False` like `==` would.  That's probably too invasive WRT the criterion you specify.

If you can change **the container themselves** (i.e., the number of places where container objects are created is much smaller than the number of places where two containers are checked for equality), then using a container subclass which overrides `__eq__` is best.

E.g.:

```
class EqMixin(object):
  def __eq__(self, other):
    return same(cont1, cont2, value_same)
```

(with `same` being as I mentioned in the A's 2nd paragraph) and

```
class EqM_list(EqMixin, list): pass
```

(and so forth for other container types you need), then wherever you have (e.g.)

```
x = list(someiter)
```

change it into

```
x = EqM_list(someiter)
```

and be sure to also catch other ways to create list objects, e.g. replace

```
x = [bah*2 for bah in buh]
```

with

```
x = EqM_list(bah*2 for bah in buh)
```

and

```
x = d.keys()
```

with

```
x = EqM_list(d.iterkeys())
```

and so forth.

Yeah, I know, what a bother -- but it's a core principle (and practice;-) of Python that builtin types (be they containers, or value types like e.g. `float`) themselves **cannot** be changed.  That's a very different philosophy from e.g. Ruby's and Javascript's (and I personally prefer it but I do see how it can seem limiting at times!).

**Edit**: the OP specific request seems to be (in terms of this answer) "how do I implement `same`" for the various container types, not how to apply it without changing the `==` into a function call.  If that's correct, then (e.g) without using iterators for simplicity:

```
def samelist(a, b, samevalue):
    if len(a) != len(b): return False
    return all(samevalue(x, y) for x, y in zip(a, b))

def samedict(a, b, samevalue):
    if set(a) != set(b): return False
    return all(samevalue(a[x], b[x]) for x in a))
```

Note that this applies to **values**, as requested, **NOT** to **keys**.  "Fuzzying up" the equality comparison of a dict's keys (or a set's members) is a *REAL* problem.  Look at it this way: first, how to you **guarantee with absolute certainty** that `samevalue(a, b) and samevalue(b, c)` totally implies and ensures `samevalue(a, c)`?  This transitivity condition does not apply to most semi-sensible "fuzzy comparisons" I've ever seen, and yet it's completely indispensable for the hash-table based containers (such as dicts and sets).  If you pass that hurdle, then the nightmare of making the hash values somehow "magically" consistent arises -- and what if two actually different keys in one dict "map to" equality in this sense with **the same** key in the other dict, which of the two corresponding values should be used then...?  This way madness lies, if you ask me, so I hope that when you say **values** you *do* mean, exactly, **values**, and **not** keys!-)

Comment: Yes, I mean values and not keys.. Correcting the question :)

Comment: Yup, I didn't think of the problem with keys that you mentioned; once I thought about it, I realized that it would have been a disaster just like you say. Luckily, no one used floats as keys (or in other words, no one was insane), so it's all good.